# My payment has been voided by the merchants but money wont show up on my credit card

Tags: credit-card, international-transfer, online-payment, wire-transfer, payment

I ordered something from the internet and payed thru credit card.

But my order has been canceled and they promised to refund me the payment I made. They say the have only authorized the payment but did not take the amount.

The authorization for the payment attempt has been voided for the payment not to reflect on my.account anymore. So I asked the bank and the money is there but I couldn't claim it. What should I do so my refund payment to reflect on my credit card, as its been 7 working days already.

Comment: i do not know what to ask to the merchants so my money that i payed would reflect on my credit card.

Comment: What was the timeline from the day you ordered, to the day you cancelled, to now? Did you actually end any money to the credit card company, or has this all been in one billing cycle?

Comment: @sandi, I noticed you tagged this with international transfer and wire transfer, but there is nothing to suggest those are relevant in the question. Could you add that information?

Comment: Do you see the original payment on your account? Did you receive confirmation in writing that your payment was voided?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the money is there". There is never any money on a credit card, there is only a debt. They took nothing, so there is nothing they should return.

Comment: Was it a Debit Card or a Credit Card?

Answer (score 2):

Executive summary:

It sounds like the merchant just did an authorization then cancelled that authorization when you cancelled the order, so there was never an actual charge so you'll never see an actual refund and there's no money to "claim".

More detail:

From your second paragraph, it sounds like they just did an authorization but never posted the transaction.

A credit card authorization is basically the merchant asking your credit card company "Does sandi have enough credit to pay this amount and if so please reserve that amount for a bit." The authorization will decrease the total credit you have available on the card, but it's not actually a charge, so if your billing cycle ends, it won't show up on your statement. Depending on which company issued your credit card, you may be able to see the authorization online, usually labelled something like "Pending transactions". Even if your credit card company doesn't show pending transactions, you'll see a decrease in your available credit, however you shouldn't see an increase in your balance.

The next step, and the only way the original merchant gets paid, is for the merchant to actually post a transaction to your card. Then it becomes a real charge that will show up on your next credit card statement and you'll be expected to pay it (unless you dispute the charge, but that's a different issue). If the charge is for the same amount as the authorization, the authorization will go away (it's now been converted to an actual charge). If the amounts are different, or the merchant never posts a transaction, the authorization will be removed by your credit card company automatically after a certain amount of time.

So it sounds like you placed the order, the merchant did an authorization to make sure you could pay for it and to reserve the money, but then you cancelled the order before the merchant could post the transaction, so you were never really charged for it. The merchant then cancelled the authorization (going by the start of your third paragraph). So there was never an actual transaction posted, you were never charged, and you never really owed any money. Your available credit went down for a bit, but now should be restored to what it was before you placed the order. You'll never see an actual refund reflected on your credit card statement because there was no actual transaction.